# How do I create a function that renames column names based on specified dictionary?

Tags: r, function, dictionary, dplyr, purrr

I am in the midst of creating a data analysis package that scrapes data from a variety of sources.  In lots of cases, the name of columns have inconsistent naming for the same type of data at each data source.

In my case, I'm looking to create a rename function that calls a dictionary formatted as a `tbl_df`, and renames the columns.

This example works when there is a new column name for all of the original columns, but not when there's an additional column that isn't part of the dictionary in the `tbl_df`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name, ~birthday, ~height,
  "John Smith", "01/20/1990", "5'10"
)

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name, ~score, ~grade,
  "John Smith", 95, 8
)


# column renaming dictionaries
people_dictionary <- tibble::tribble(
  ~namePeople, ~nameActual,
  "name", "studentName",
  "birthday", "dob",
  "height", "height"
)

test_dictionary <- tibble::tribble(
  ~nameTest, ~nameActual,
  "name", "studentName",
  "score", "examScore",
  "grade", "schoolGrade"
)

rename_function <- function(data, data_source = "people") {
  # find dictionary based on data source
  if (data_source == "people") {
    actual_names_df <- people_dictionary
  }
  if (data_source == "test") {
    actual_names_df <- test_dictionary
  }

  # get column names of data
  original_names <- colnames(data)

  # create column name filter depending on data source
  name_columns <- case_when(
    data_source == "people" ~ "namePeople",
    data_source == "people" ~ "nameTest"
  )

  # Match Original Names to Renamed Column Names
  actual_names <-
    seq_along(original_names) %>%
    purrr::map_chr(function(x) {
      actual <-
        actual_names_df %>%
        # rlang used to unquote dynamic name column
        filter((!!rlang::sym(name_columns)) == original_names[x]) %>%
        .$nameActual
    })

  # rename columns
  data <- data %>%
    purrr::set_names(actual_names)
}

renamed_df1 <- df1 %>% rename_function(data_source = "people")

# original df
df1
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   name       birthday   height
#>   <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
#> 1 John Smith 01/20/1990 5'10

# renamed columns of df1
renamed_df1
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   studentName dob        height
#>   <chr>       <chr>      <chr> 
#> 1 John Smith  01/20/1990 5'10

# additional column not named in dictionary
df3 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name, ~birthday, ~height, ~weight,
  "John Smith", "01/20/1990", "5'10", 165
)

df3 %>% rename_function(data_source = "people")
#> Error: Result 4 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

There are a few pieces of my rename function that I believe could be improved upon:

1. Is there a better way to call the right dictionary (`tbl_df`) that isn't a ton of `if` statements?  Would I be able to create a `tbl_df` or `csv` that has a column for `data_source` and another column that lists the name of the `tbl_df` within the package?

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~data_source,    ~dictionary_name,
      "people", "people_dictionary",
        "test",   "test_dictionary"
  )
```

2. How can I re-work my function to follow a similar workflow but not get the rename error when all columns don't have new names in the dictionary?
3. Is there a better process for storing "dictionaries" in an `r` package for my use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can have a single dictionary for all imported datasets.
A trick is to use a named vector for the old and new variable names with `rename`. You can still have the dictionary in a `tibble` and create named vector with `tibble::deframe`

[note that the named vector should be `c(new1 = old1, new2 = old2,..)`

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Our dictionary
dictionary <- tibble::tibble(
  new = c("studentName", "dob", "height", "examScore", "schoolGrade"),
  old = c("name", "birthday", "height", "score", "grade")
)

dictionary
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   new         old     
#>   <chr>       <chr>   
#> 1 studentName name    
#> 2 dob         birthday
#> 3 height      height  
#> 4 examScore   score   
#> 5 schoolGrade grade

# The data with a column that is not present in the dictionary
data <- tibble::tibble(
  name = rnorm(5),
  score = rnorm(5),
  grade = rnorm(5),
  new_var = rnorm(5)
)

data
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>     name  score  grade new_var
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1  0.678 -0.431  0.753  1.43  
#> 2  0.602 -0.532  1.15   0.356 
#> 3  1.68   1.40   0.410  0.0729
#> 4  0.817  1.84  -0.292  0.523 
#> 5 -0.316  0.954 -1.02   1.16


# get the data variable names where there is a new name in the dictionary
vars_found_in_dictionary <- intersect(names(data), unique(dictionary$old))

# create a temporary dictionary as a named vector
temp_dict <- dictionary %>% dplyr::filter(old %in% vars_found_in_dictionary) %>% tibble::deframe()

temp_dict
#> studentName   examScore schoolGrade 
#>      "name"     "score"     "grade"

# rename those variables only
data %>% dplyr::rename(!!temp_dict)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   studentName examScore schoolGrade new_var
#>         <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1       0.678    -0.431       0.753  1.43  
#> 2       0.602    -0.532       1.15   0.356 
#> 3       1.68      1.40        0.410  0.0729
#> 4       0.817     1.84       -0.292  0.523 
#> 5      -0.316     0.954      -1.02   1.16
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Also, when you create the function, it is best to have a check if there are no matching variable names in the dictionary

**EDIT**

Since you want to select the dictionary

```r
library(tidyverse)

people <- tibble::tibble(
  name = rnorm(5),
  birthady = rnorm(5),
  new_var = rnorm(5)
  )

test <- tibble::tibble(
  grade = rnorm(5),
  score = rnorm(5)
  )

people_dictionary <- tibble::tibble(
  new = c("studentName", "dob", "height"),
  old = c("name", "birthday", "height")
  )


test_dictionary <- tibble::tibble(
  new = c( "examScore", "schoolGrade"),
  old = c("score", "grade")
  )

dictionary_list <- 
  list( "people" = "people_dictionary",
        "test" =   "test_dictionary"
  )


  dictionary <- function(data) { 

    dictionary <- deparse(substitute(data))

    eval(parse(text= dictionary_list[dictionary][[1]]))

    }


dictionary(people)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   new         old     
#>   <chr>       <chr>   
#> 1 studentName name    
#> 2 dob         birthday
#> 3 height      height

dictionary(test)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   new         old  
#>   <chr>       <chr>
#> 1 examScore   score
#> 2 schoolGrade grade
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The issue I foresee with a single dictionary is really around size.  Some of my actual data sources have over 400 column names.  If I did a single tibble it would be calling in a massive sized tibble each time.

Comment: I understand. Though a tibble of size 400 x2 is not really massive. Even 1000x2. In any case, you can have a few dictionaries and apply the code above to do it for each dictionary

Comment: One additional question.  What is the difference between using a named vector (i.e. above), rename_all(~ as.character(dictionary$new)[match(., dictionary$old)]), or rename_at?  Pro's or Con's to each approach?

Comment: I couldn;t make your code to work but I wouldn't use `rename_all` since it refers to *all* variables. One approach is to use `rename_at` as follows: 

`vars_to_change <- intersect(names(data), dictionary$old)`
`vars_new_names <- dictionary$new[match(vars_to_change, dictionary$old)]`

`data %>% rename_at(vars_to_change, ~ vars_new_names)`
This way you don't mess with creating temp_dictionary and named vectors. I can't see any major differences so I can't say for prons or cons. perhaps a more experienced person can chip in here.